# jquerymobile pages and Phonegap deviceready event onLoad

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, onload

I know this has been discussed before, but with no results for me.

The problem is that deviceready() is only fired once, the first time on "list" page. I can´t get it to work on article pages. And when I go back from a "article" page to "articlelist" the event is still out of work. I need the menubutton operative in every data-role="page".

The js:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
 }


 function onDeviceReady() {
   document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);       
  }

   function onMenuKeyDown() {
    alert('Menu pressed');
    }
 </script>
```

The HTML:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
 <div id="list" data-role="page">
   <ul id="articleList" data-role="listview">
    <li id="list1"><a id="link1" href="#article1"></li>  
    <li id="list2"><a id="link1" href="#article2"></li>  
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="article1" data-role="page">Content</div>
<div id="article2" data-role="page">Content</div>
```

I'm with: cordova-1.5.0 /jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.2 /jquery-1.7.1 /Android

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

I just quickly tested this in the app I'm working on right now  and it works.  Phonegap-1.6.1 and jquery.mobile-1.1.0  final

Perhaps you should try upgrading your phonegap and jquery.mobile

Comment: Yeap!! Tested with jquery.mobile-1.1.0 final & phonegap 1.7rc1 and working great!!